# Having a hard time making a post request to a JSON file using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-http

there!  Pretty new to Angular and Javascript in general, I'm trying to make a simple one page toy app where you can add and view customers using a JSON file as storage.  I've been able to get my JSON to display but I've gotten stuck on adding new entries using a form.  I've been checking in on the server and when I click submit not post request is made.  Any help would be much appreciated!  thanks!

this is my form

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerAddController as addCtrl">
  <form
  ng-submit="addCtrl.addCustomer()" novalidate>
    <h2>Add a new customer </h2>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.name">Name: <input type="text"/></fieldset>

    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.email">Email: <input type="email"/></fieldset>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.phone">phone: <input type="text"/></fieldset>
    <h3>Address</h3>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.street">Street: <input type="text"/></fieldset>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.city">City: <input type="text"/></fieldset>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.state">State: <input type="text"/></fieldset>
    <fieldset ng-model="addCtrl.customer.zip">Zip: <input type="text"/></fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

and this is my app.js file

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);
app.controller('CustomerListController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('customers.json').then(function(res){
      $scope.customers = res.data;
   });
});

app.controller('CustomerAddController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
     $http.post('customers.json').then(function(res){
         $scope.customers = res.data;
     })
     .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if (!data.success) {
            $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
          } else {
            $scope.message = data.message;
          }
      });

    };
});
```

Comment: I can't see where do you incude the data in the add `post` method. On other words, You just create a `post` request without adding the data.

Comment: @MoshFeu `post` wasn't the only thing that OP is missing.. he also messed up with binding stuff & controller code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very 1st thing you should to is,

Attach `ng-model` directive to `input` fields not to `fieldset`, as they are only tends to work with `input` & `textarea`

```
<form ng-submit="addCtrl.addCustomer()" novalidate>
    <h2>Add a new customer </h2>
    <fieldset>
      Name: <input type="text" ng-model="addCtrl.customer.name" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="addCtrl.customer.email" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        phone: <input type="text" ng-model="addCtrl.customer.phone" />
    </fieldset>
    <h3>Address</h3>
    <fieldset>
        Street: <input ng-model="addCtrl.customer.street" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        City: <input ng-model="addCtrl.customer.city" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        State: <input ng-model="addCtrl.customer.state" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        Zip: <input ng-model="addCtrl.customer.zip" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Other than that as you are using `controllerAs` so controller data should bounded to `this` context. Also post calls seems to have `.json` in URL, which should be actual server `URL`, so those parameter will get passed with payload & don't forget to pass data in `post` request as @Kyle pointed out in below answer.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);

app.controller('CustomerListController', function($http){
  var self = this;
  $http.get('customers.json').then(function(res){
     self.customers = res.data;
  });
});

app.controller('CustomerAddController', function($http){
     var self = this;
     self.addCustomer = function() {
     //below serverUrl would be server where you configured post request
     //pass self.customer in that, will pass whole customer filled form
     $http.post(serverUrl, self.customer).then(function(res){
         self.customers = res.data;
     })
     .success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if (!data.success) {
            self.errorName = data.errors.name;
          } else {
            self.message = data.message;
          }
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: He is missing the data in the `post` request, isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu Correct(thats is part of answer).. but for making initial thing working, he also need to do the mentioned changes..

Comment: thank you!  I'm still trying to get to grips with the difference between using $scope and this, and did not know that mg-model wouldn't work on a fieldset so this has been very helpful.

Comment: OK then. Please accept the answer so it will help to other people.

Comment: @mrdavidharms do [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)..if it does help you.. Thanks :-)

Comment: if it's not too much of a hassle could you explain how you include the data in a post request?

Comment: @mrdavidharms Glad to know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send data with your $http.post()

```
$http.post("customers.json",data).then...
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http